# get static function from inherited

Tags: php, yii2, php-5.6

When I use

```
DemoStyle::order(); // returns {{%demo_style}} but not 'site.site_demo_style'
DemoLayout::order(); // returns {{%demo_layout}} but not 'site.site_demo_layout'
```

I get wrong table name.
I believe it is ActiveRecord::tableName() returns wrong name.
How to get tableName from DemoStyle and DemoLayout.

```
class Sortable extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function order()
    {
        return self::tableName();
    }
}

class DemoStyle extends Sortable
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'site.site_demo_style';
    }
}

class DemoLayout extends Sortable
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'site.site_demo_layout';
    }
}
```

Please do not vote down.

Comment: You need to be clear and post complete code. If you expect upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Why do you use static methods? When you define an abstract method and don't use static context, this works for me:

```
 <?php
    abstract class Sortable 
    {
        public abstract function tableName();


        public function order()
        {
            return $this->tableName();
        }
    }

    class DemoStyle extends Sortable
    {
        public function tableName()
        {
            return 'site.site_demo_style';
        }
    }

    class DemoLayout extends Sortable
    {
        public function tableName()
        {
            return 'site.site_demo_layout';
        }
    }

echo (new DemoStyle)->order();
```

**UPDATE 2**

Example in php documentation for static context:  [Late Static Bindings](http://%20php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: Now you have change your listining, and for me it works fine!

Comment: What do you mean fine? Do you get 'site.site_demo_style' ?

Comment: These classes and methods are parts of the Yii2, that's why I use them.

Comment: On the following site, you can find solution for static context: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Answer (score 0):

In this situation works

```
static::tableName()
```